# Modelo heterocesdástico de efeitos mistos via função lmer

Tags: r, modelagem, regressão, model, lme4

Estou ajustando um modelo de efeitos mistos o qual devido a heterocedasticidade observada foi necessário incluir um efeito para acomodá-la. Para tanto, utilizando a função `lme` do pacote `nlme` isso foi fácil de ser resolvido, veja o código abaixo:

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)
Model1 <- lme(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                     (Var4)+(Var5),
                    random = ~1|Var6, Data1, method="REML",
                   weights = varIdent(form=~1|Var7))
#Var6: É um fator com diversos níveis.
#Var7: É uma variável Dummy.
```

No entanto, eu preciso reajustar o modelo descrito acima utilizando o pacote `lme4`, ou seja, utilizando a função `lmer`. É de conhecimento e muitos são os materiais que informam algumas limitações existentes no `lme4`, como por exemplo, modelar a heterocedásticidade. O que me motivou a reajustar esse modelo é o fato de que eu tenho o interesse em utilizar um pacote específico que em casos de modelos mistos ele só aceita se estes forem ajustados por meio da função `lmer`. Como eu poderia resolver esta situação? Abaixo se encontra boa parte do modelo ajustado utilizando a função lmer, no entanto, este modelo não está considerando o efeito para modelar a heterocedásticidade observada.

```
Model2 <- lmer(log(Var1)~log(Var2)+log(Var3)+
                          (Var4)+(Var5)+(1|Var6),
                    Data1, REML=T)
```

Quanto a escolha do efeito aleatório (Var6) e a inclusão do efeito para considerar a heterogeneidade por níveis da variável (Var7), estas foram analisadas cuidadosamente, no entanto, não colocarei aqui todo o procedimento para não ficar um post extenso e ser mais objetivo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numa resposta do [R-sig-mixed-models](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-mixed-models), Douglas Bates ([GoogleScholar](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=z3KmA0sAAAAJ&hl=en), [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Douglas-Bates)) dá a seguinte resposta a uma pergunta sobre a possibilidade de modelar o problema da heteroscedasticidade da distribuição da resposta em modelos mistos.

> As far as I know there is not yet the capability in lme4 to model
> heteroscedasticity in the distribution of the response given the random
> effects.

Tradução Google.

> Pelo que sei, ainda não há capacidade no lme4 para modelar
> heterocedasticidade na distribuição da resposta dada a aleatoriedade
> efeitos.

Creio que a melhor maneira é aninhar `Var7` na variável dos efeitos aleatórios `Var6`. Isso é fácil de fazer e um gráfico `qqnorm` dá um ajuste melhor que `Model1` ou `Model2`.

```
library(nlme)
library(lme4)

Model1 <- lme(log(Var1) ~ log(Var2) + log(Var3) + Var4 + Var5,
              random = ~1|Var6, Data1, method = "REML",
              weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Var7))

Model2 <- lmer(log(Var1) ~ log(Var2) + log(Var3) + Var4 + Var5 + (1|Var6),
               Data1, REML=TRUE)
```

Os modelos acima são os da pergunta, agora o novo modelo.

```
Model3 <- lmer(log(Var1) ~ log(Var2) + log(Var3) + Var4 + Var5 + (1|Var6/Var7),
               Data1, REML=TRUE)
```

A saída destes comandos foi omitida.

```
summary(Model1)
summary(Model2)
summary(Model3)
```

E finalmente os três gráficos. Sem interpretação, o `Model3` é claramente a melhor opção. Note-se o outlier dos resíduos nos dois primeiros gráficos que não foi necessário remover no terceiro modelo.

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
qqnorm(resid(Model1))
qqline(resid(Model1), col = "red")
qqnorm(resid(Model2))
qqline(resid(Model2), col = "red")
qqnorm(resid(Model3))
qqline(resid(Model3), col = "red")
par(op)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### Leitura dos dados

```
google_id <- "1cr9-KOOR_RTDN4_nHizpvKBZ0yDAKGoV"
google_file <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", google_id)
Data1 <- read.csv2(google_file)
```

Comment: Obrigado Rui!! Muito boa sua explicação e solução!